# OpenGl es 2.0 2D plane rotation

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, rotation, 2d, projection

I have been working on getting some quads with textures to display properly using OpenGL es 2.0 on iPhone platform. I started off following the tutorial here

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/ios_lesson_02__first_triangle/50001/

Which basically just makes a simple triangle and displays to the screen using very simple shaders. The problem arises when i rotate the triangle in Z axis.

This is how the traingle looks without any rotation applied and with 90 rotation in the Z Axis.

[image]

I have used the source code project from the NEHE tutorial site and the only changes i made are to add a world matrix in the vertex shader

```
//the incoming vertex' position
attribute vec4 position;

//and its color
attribute vec3 color;

//the varying statement tells the shader pipeline that this variable
//has to be passed on to the next stage (so the fragment shader)
varying lowp vec3 colorVarying;

//added this matrix
uniform mat4 world;

//the shader entry point is the main method
void main()
{    
    colorVarying = color; //save the color for the fragment shader
    gl_Position = world * position; //multiplied the matrix with the position
}
```

The pixel shader just out puts the color.

In the program in have set up and passed the world matrix as follows

```
GLKMatrix4 _world = GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(1.5708, 0, 0, 1);
glUniformMatrix4fv(m_worldMat, 1, GL_FALSE, _world.m);
```

This is the simplest way I could get the problem to be replicated for this question. I have also tried creating a orthographic camera which goes from 0 to screen width and 0 to screen height.

-------------------Iteration 2 After Suggestion from q______b-----------------------------

so i edited the code to have orhtographic projection.
First i Changed the triangle to a rectangle. Here is the vertex set up

```
  right = 0.75 * m_renderbufferWidth;
    left = 0.25 * m_renderbufferWidth;
    top = 0.55 * m_renderbufferHeight;
    bottom = 0.45 * m_renderbufferHeight;

    widthOver2 = (right - left) * 0.5;
    heightOver2 = (bottom - top) * 0.5;

    //push the vertex data into the buffer
    //4 floats define one vertex (x, y, z and w), first one is lower left
    geometryData.push_back(-widthOver2); geometryData.push_back(heightOver2 ); geometryData.push_back(1.0); geometryData.push_back(1.0);
    //we go counter clockwise, so lower right vertex next
    geometryData.push_back(widthOver2); geometryData.push_back(heightOver2); geometryData.push_back(1.0); geometryData.push_back(1.0);
    //top left vertex is last
    geometryData.push_back(-widthOver2); geometryData.push_back(-heightOver2); geometryData.push_back(1.0); geometryData.push_back(1.0);
    //top right vertex is last
    geometryData.push_back(widthOver2); geometryData.push_back(-heightOver2); geometryData.push_back(1.0); geometryData.push_back(1.0);
```

Here is the changed drawing code. I now have the orthographic camera going from 0, 0 to screen dimensions and i created the rectangle around the origin and translated to the middle of the screen.

```
GLKMatrix4 temp = GLKMatrix4Identity;
GLKMatrix4 _world = GLKMatrix4Identity;
temp = GLKMatrix4Multiply(GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(left + widthOver2, top + heightOver2, 0), GLKMatrix4MakeRotation(1.5708, 0, 0, 1));
_world = GLKMatrix4Multiply(GLKMatrix4MakeScale(1, 1, 1), temp);
glUniformMatrix4fv(m_worldMat, 1, GL_FALSE, _world.m);

GLKMatrix4 _projection = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, m_renderbufferWidth, 0, m_renderbufferHeight , -100, 100);
glUniformMatrix4fv(m_projectionMat, 1, GL_FALSE, _projection.m);


//initiate the drawing process, we want a triangle, start at index 0 and draw 3 vertices
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Here is the vertex shader part.

```
void main()
{    
    colorVarying = color; //save the color for the fragment shader
    gl_Position = projection * world * position; //multiplied the matrix with the position
}
```

I am still facing the same issue. I have updated the link from the original post with the lastest screenshot as i do not have enough rep to post more than 2 links

Please help and thank you for the suggestions and help so far.

Comment: And what is the problem? You did not write it. If problem is triangle aspect ratio then something wrong with your matrix.

Comment: Sorry I realize now that I did not mention the problem. When the triangle is rotated it gets squished to fit into the screen rather than remaining the same size.

Comment: And how do you rotate it? It looks like you not doing it with rotation matrix, but doing something else instead since all coeficients in call to GLKMatrix4MakeRotation are 0 and 1.

Comment: I pasted the code after setting the rotation to 0 for taking the screenshot. I have fixed that now. I was rotating using the GLKMatrix4MakeRotation

Comment: and how do you setup your view? clearly you have a problem with aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your bottom left has logical coordinates is {-1,-1}, top right is {1, 1}, that is square, but screen is not square that is why you have a distortion, so you have to adjust that by setting correct projection matrix. you can calculate it with GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho for your case.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply i am trying to use the GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho.  I ll post the code in a bit. I have already tried this in my original project but i got the same results.

Comment: I have edited the original question with the implementation. Please check and help

Comment: and why do you think you facing the same issue, rectangles are the same, just rotated as you wanted to.

Comment: they definetely look squished to me. I ll put texture on the rectangle which would give us a better idea. I will post updated screen shots as soon as i reach home. Please take a look again. Thank You.

Comment: I even copied and pasted it into image editor to check, they are identical. This is just an illusion this time.